# How do you migrate SQL Server 2000 reports to SQL Server 2005/2008?

Tags: reporting-services

Can anyone explain how to import or migrate SQL Server 2000 reports to SQL Server 2005 or 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you just need to port your data from your old ReportServer database to the new one. The report RDL is stored in the Catalog table, for instance, and you just need to import all of that. That table also includes all of the path names you've defined. The subscriptions table contains all the subscription that have been defined, as you would expect.

I've not done a full migration between the two, but it should be relatively straight forward -- just dedicate a day or so to matching up all the fields and then run with it.